# Odd behavior of yield inside a if then block

Tags: python, if-statement, generator, control-flow, yield-keyword

I have a function that returns a generator or a list depending on a flag.

Yet even when I set the flag to `list` the function still returns a generator; also doesn't print the flag.

I expect the print statement prior to the yield command to be evaluated first.  Also for that matter if the flag is set to `list` I do not expect the `generator` block to evaluate at all.

```
import os

def get_iterator_all_files_name(dir_path, flag):
    if flag == 'generator':
        print(flag)
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_path):
            for f in filenames:
                yield os.path.join(dirpath, f)
    elif flag == 'list':
        print(flag)
        paths = list()
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_path):
            for f in filenames:
                paths.append(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
        return paths
```

Using the function...

```
file_path = 'path/to/files'
flag = 'list'
foo = get_iterator_all_files_name(file_path, flag)
type(foo)
```

Which produces the result...

`generator`

Which is not what I expect; I was expecting list.

Comment: A question is "solved" if it has an accepted answer. There is no reason to put word "solved" into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function has the word `yield` in it, it's a generator. No exceptions. The code will not be evaluated until iteration is attempted.

Just call `list` on the result instead:

```
def get_iterator_all_files_name(dir_path):
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_path):
        for f in filenames:
            yield os.path.join(dirpath, f)

file_path = 'path/to/files'
foo = list(get_iterator_all_files_name(file_path))
```

You can modify your function to return a generator if you really wanted to preserve the `flag` functionality. You can also make `paths` a list comprehension, which can simplify the function:

```
def get_iterator_all_files_name(dir_path, flag):
    if flag == 'generator':
        return (os.path.join(dirpath, f) for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_path) for f in filenames)
    elif flag == 'list':
        return [os.path.join(dirpath, f) for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_path) for f in filenames]
```

Comment: but if we send flag='generator' this will also return list

Comment: @ravishankarchavare The point is, if you need a generator, don't call `list`. If you need a list, call `list`.

Comment: OK Now understand scenario

Answer (score 2):

Any function that has a `yield` statement becomes a generator function, and therefore, its `return` statement has a different meaning (as compared to the `return` statement of a normal function).
If you really need the `get_iterator_all_files_name` function to return a generator sometimes and a list at other times, one way of doing it is this:

1. Define one more function (say `my_gen_func`) to do what you're doing now inside your `if` clause. This new function would therefore be a generator
   function (since it would have a `yield` statement).
2. Inside the `get_iterator_all_files_name` function, modify the `if` clause, to just have a call to `my_gen_func`, and return its
   return-value. (Now, your `get_iterator_all_files_name` function is no longer a generator function, but is just a normal function, since it doesn't have a `yield` statement)
3. Your `elif` clause can remain the same.